# C++, initialize a 2d array. error:subscript requires array or pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

New to C++. Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


const int Gardensize = 20;//Garden size, a 20X20 2d array
const int initialants = 100;//100 initial ants
const int initialdoodlebug = 5;//5 intial bug
const int antType = 1;// 
const int doodleType = 2;//
const char antchar = 'O';//ant will display'O'in the window
const char bugchar = 'X';//


class Garden;
class Organism;
class Ant;
class Doodlebug;


class Garden {
    friend class Organism;
    friend class Ant;
    friend class  Doodlebug;
public:
    Garden();
    ~Garden();
    int checkType(int x, int y);//check the element type (ant or bug)in the grid
    void Display();

private:
    Organism grid[Gardensize][Gardensize];  //C2079 'Garden::grid' uses undefined class 'Organism' I have already define the class Organism in advance,have no ideal how to fix this error.

};
Garden::Garden() { //initialize the garden, set all elements in grid to "NULL"
    for (int i = 0; i < Gardensize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Gardensize; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = NULL;   //error:subscript requires array or pointer 
        }
    }
}
Garden::~Garden() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Gardensize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Gardensize; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] != NULL) {
               grid[i][j] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}
void Garden::Display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Gardensize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Gardensize; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j].getType == antType) {
                cout << antchar;
            }
            else if (grid[i][j].getType == NULL) {
                cout << ".";
            }
            else if (grid[i][j].getType == doodleType) {
                cout << bugchar;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int Garden::checkType(int x, int y) { 

    return grid[x][y].getType();
}

class Organism {
    friend class Garden;
public:
    virtual int getType() {}; //
    virtual void breed() {};
    virtual bool starve() {};
    virtual int move( int &breedtoken) {};

protected:
    int x = -1;              //initial xy place
    int y = -1;
    Garden garden;
    bool moved;             //used to define whether org has moved or not
    int breedtoken = 0;     //used to define whether org need to breed
};

class Ant : public Organism {
public:
    Ant() {}; //
    Ant(int x, int y, Garden* g)//initial a ant object by define the xy place in the gardene
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        garden = *g;
    }
    ~Ant() {};
   
    virtual int getType() {  
        return antType;
    }
    virtual int move(int &breedtoken);
    virtual void breed() {};
    virtual bool starve() { return false; };// ant wont starve


};
int Ant::move(int& breedtoken) {
    int dir = rand() % 4;// randomly select direction
    switch (dir) {
        case 0 :// 0move upwards
            if( this->x > 0 && garden.grid[x - 1][y] == NULL ){
               garden.grid[x-1][y] = garden.grid[x][y];
               garden.grid[x][y] = NULL;
               x--;
            }
            break;
        case 1:// 1 move downwards
            if (this->x < Gardensize - 1 && garden.grid[x + 1][y] == NULL) {
                garden.grid[x + 1][y] = garden.grid[x][y];
                garden.grid[x][y] = NULL;
                x++;
            }
            break;
        case 2: // 2 move leftwards
            if (this->y > 0 && garden.grid[x][y-1] == NULL) {
                garden.grid[x][y-1] = garden.grid[x][y];
                garden.grid[x][y] = NULL;
                y--;
            }
            break;
        case 3: // 3 move to right
            if (this->y < Gardensize- 1 && garden.grid[x][y + 1] == NULL) {
                garden.grid[x][y + 1] = garden.grid[x][y];
                garden.grid[x][y] = NULL;
                y++;
            }
            break;
            this->breedtoken += 1;
            return breedtoken;
    }
     
}
class Doodlebug :public Organism {
public:
    Doodlebug() {}; 
    Doodlebug(int x, int y, Garden* g)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        garden = *g;
    }
    virtual int getType() {    
        return doodleType;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));//
    Garden garden;
    int antCount = 0;  //Ant counter, used to intilize 100 ants
    int DoodleCount = 0;
    Ant antarray[initialants]; 
    Doodlebug doodlebugarray[initialdoodlebug];

    while (antCount < initialants) {
        int x = rand() % Gardensize;
        int y = rand() % Gardensize;
        if (garden.checkType(x, y) == NULL) {

            antarray[antCount] =  Ant(x, y, &garden); //initilize 100 ants
            antCount++;
        }
    }
    while (DoodleCount < initialdoodlebug) {
        int x = rand() % Gardensize;
        int y = rand() % Gardensize;
        if (garden.checkType(x, y) == NULL) {

            doodlebugarray[DoodleCount] = Doodlebug(x, y, &garden); //用数组的模式创建100只蚂蚁
            DoodleCount++;
        }
    }


    garden.Display();//display
}
```

The project is not finished yet. Right now, the code can initialize 100ants and 5 bugs. It can run properly but keep showing"subscript requires array or pointer " wherever I write grid[i][j] in the for loop. and "   'Garden::grid' uses undefined class 'Organism'" when I define the "Organism grid[][]" in the Garden class. I wonder to know how can i fix these 2 errors, and what's wrong with my 2d array grid?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: As a hint to the root cause of your problem: To create an object of a class, you need the full *definition* of the class, it's not enough with a declaration. Considering that you use polymorphism, the simple solution is to use *pointers* to objects, for which a declaration is enough.

Comment: On another note: The symbol `NULL` is a C-compatibility macro for null *pointers*. C++ doesn't have "null values", and if you return an `int` value then you should compare against an actual `int` value. Also, if you declare a function to return a value, then you should *always* return a value, otherwise you risk *undefined behavior*. If you have an abstract virtual function in a base class (a function you don't really want to define/implement) define it as abstract (e.g. `virtual int getType() = 0;`)

Comment: Your design also seems flawed, with way to many `friend` declarations. Also the `getType()` function is an anti-pattern. All in all I would recommend you spend some more time studying design and invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the 2d array is caused, because you try to create an array of `Organism`s, which are up to that point only declared, not defined, and so the compiler doesn't know their size and can't create an array of them. This can b fixed by reordering your classes, or by putting the class declarations in headers. You can also just replace the array with a dynamic array (double pointer), and initialize it after they have been declared.

The other error is just a consequence of the first, fix it and they will both disapear.

You should try reading some book about c or c++ first, and learn a bit about pointers, and design and structure of c++ programs